# Windows 10 shortcuts - onenote vs cortana

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-10, cortana

I'm happy with my windows 10. It looks just like windows 7, but nicer. There's just this little thing...

I like OneNote snipping tool. At the press of <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> it lets you pick a region on the screen and put it on your clipboard. Awesome, using that at least 10 times a day.

Since Windows 10 when I press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> it starts Cortana Search. Which is probably also awesome, I just want it to occupy another shortcut - say - <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> or something else far away for now.

Q: Is it possible to move or disable the keyboard shortcuts of Cortana?

Comment: [Your using the wrong shortcut.](https://blogs.office.com/2013/06/27/windows-8-1-preview-and-a-workaround-for-your-favorite-wins-shortcut-key/) The shortcut you were using wouldn't have worked on Windows 8.1 either.

Comment: Still, I am a creature of habit. I would prefer changing cortana if that's possible

Comment: It isn't the shortcut though.  So you would have to disable Cortana, change the shortcut to Cortana, AND change the shortcut in a program which doesn't have an option to change what the shortcut is.  Much easier to adapt to the new realities.

Comment: Changing is not an option in both? I would have expected an ugly registry hack, but if that's the case it stops

Comment: I don't know of a way to disable the Cortana Win+S shortcut, but if you would prefer to use a different shortcut for Cortana, you can use Win+Q, which opens Cortana for text entry like Win+S, or you can also use Win+C, which opens Cortana and starts listening for voice input.

Comment: Windows Shift S only works in OneNote 365, so this is still an issue for people using older (2010) versions of office.

Comment: Having the same issue, not sure what Ramhound means by "using the wrong shortcut". Win+S is the default key combo for creating screen clippings in One Note and always has been.

Comment: @JustinBuser - Windows 8.1 changed the shortcut for search to `Windows + S` which means the keyboard shortcut for OneNote to take a screenshot was changed to `Windows + Shift + S`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

OneNote was updated in Oct 2013 and changed the shortcut to following on systems running Windows 8.1 and greater.

> Windows + Shift + S

[Source](https://blogs.office.com/2013/06/27/windows-8-1-preview-and-a-workaround-for-your-favorite-wins-shortcut-key/)

Here is a crude animation showing that OneNote's screen-clip functionality still works on Windows 10 using the shortcut **Windows+Shift+S**.  The only thing that is not shown, which I am unable to show, is the **S** being hightlighted on the on-screen keyboard since OneNote which is installed on my computer captures the shortcut before its displayed on the on-screen keyboard.

[image]

Comment: OK considering this is the best possible alternative, I'll accept this answer. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: What does your comment have to do with the question?

Comment: `Windows + Shift + S` does not appear to work for *Windows 10* + *OneNote 2010*

Comment: @Pressacco - That is interesting considering I just confirmed it still worked.

Comment: @Pressacco - What does Outlook 2010 have to do with a OneNote 2010 shortcut?  The shortcut has not been changed since Windows 8.1 was released.

Comment: @Ramhound: Strange. I have a fresh install of Windows 10 Pro and OneNote 2010... `Window + Shift + S` does not do anything on my laptop.

Comment: @Pressacco - Updated answer with photographic proof it the shrotcut works like I claim.

Answer (score 24):

This turns off the Windows built in Win+S shortcut (removing it from Cortana), additionally a value of "SR" for instance would also disable Win+R (run).

`[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced]
    "DisabledHotkeys"="S"`

After setting this registry key restart Windows and Win+S will work for OneNote again.

I'm not really sure why so many people who don't know the actual answer to a question still choose to chime in, it's kind of frustrating how often I end up on Stack Exchange these days only to discover that people are providing misinformation or useless conjecture.

Comment: Note that it has to be a String Value. Also, you don't need to restart. It's faster to log off (sign out) and log on again.

Comment: Another alternative to restarting is to open Task Manager, end OneNote and restart Windows Explorer; then, once you restart OneNote, all will be well.

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me:

First remove the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> binding from Search:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced] "DisabledHotkeys"="S"
```

Then get OneNote to bind to just <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> again:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\OneNote\Options\Other] "ScreenClippingShortcutKey"=0x00000053
```

credit to:   http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-onenote/onenote-screen-clipping-tool-hotkeys-in-windows-10/f454aa9d-c295-478c-8496-4146c1ba5876?page=2

Comment: I think your second step to get OneNote to bind Win-S would be useful for those versions (2013 and above) that rebind it to Win-Shift-S? So that I can rebind it back to the better Win-S shortcut? It wasn't necessary for me as I'm on OneNote 2010 which still uses Win-S by default. I just needed to log off and on again after the first step.

Comment: What's wild is that OneNote2007's context menu from the taskbar dock claims that Win-S will work for screen clipping - I have no idea if that's actually true or not, since Win-S has been hijacked by Cortana in Windows 10 (I had to do the free upgrade from 7), but Win-Shift-S does work in OneNote2007.